# Possible to build pure python package for ros1 and ros2 with one package.xml/CMakeLists file?

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-melodic, catkin, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a pure python pacakge. Currently I have a CMakeLists and package.xml file set up so that it builds correctly with ros 1. If I add the `ament_python` build type to my package.xml then it also works great for ros 2 but then I can't build it for ros 1.

Is there any way out of this that doesn't require me to keep two branches/separate ros2 repo (that isn't writing a giant cmake file with lots of conditionals)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335437/possible-to-build-pure-python-package-for-ros1-and-ros2-with-one-package.xml/cmakelists-file?/) by [Jari](https://answers.ros.org/users/14761/jari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-10-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of format version 3 of the package manifest the `build_type` tag supports a `condition` attribute (see [REP 149](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0149.html#build-type-multiple)) which allows you to specify two different build types - e.g. one for ROS 1 and another for ROS 2.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jari](https://answers.ros.org/users/14761/jari/) on 2019-10-16**:
Excellent. Can I use this now or is this coming in a future update?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-10-16**:
That feature is already available for quite some time. So you can use it now.

**Comment by [Jari](https://answers.ros.org/users/14761/jari/) on 2019-10-17**:
So apparently this works for catkin only if I put in two `build_type` tags and ensure that the `cmake` build type tag with condition `$ROS_VERSION == 1` is listed first.

As far as I can tell catkin is ignoring that tag whereas colcon seems to be using it correctly. Does that sound right?

Edit: the condition that does work (and it's great that it does) is

```
  <export>
      <build_type condition="$ROS_VERSION == 1">cmake</build_type>
      <build_type condition="$ROS_VERSION == 2">ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
```

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-10-17**:
I would certainly call that a bug. Would you mind trying https://github.com/ros/catkin/pull/1038 and comment if that resolves the problem for you.